# Get the Message Id or thread Id immediately after sent gmail

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-api, gmail-addons

Can I get the message id or  thread id immediately after sent gmail using google script or gmail API.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Acording to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send), when you send a message using `Users.messages.send` method of the API, the response will be a [`messages.resource`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) which includes the message Id and the thread Id of the message just sent.

Comment: Thank you Iván for your answer, but I do not try to create another send button my idea is to use the same gmail send button in the compose view and when the email is sent I can get the message id or thread id.